# Wordpress site shows a white page for site/wp_admin. A login returns again to the login screen

Tags: wp-admin, login, wp-login-form

The situation for a site that worked for years.

- The Site frontend works
- The theme I use is TwentySixteen
- I tried to open site/wp_admin
- Login Screen shows up
- I enter the credentials
- Login Screen Shows up again.
- Calling site/wp_admin directly shows white page
- Entering wrong credentials shows a correct warning that the name, password pair is wrong.
- I can reset a password for the user. I receive an email and can change the password.
- I usually have a 2 factor plugin, https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/google-authenticator/
- Entering a wrong code shows a correct warning
- Disabled the google-authenticator plugin by renaming the folder.
- Tried login again. Doesn't work.
- Used another second admin account . Blank screen either
- Reset Password for second account, worked.
- Login reopens login page again.
- Disabling all Addins via SQL table WP_Options table (Clearing Active_plugins field) doesn't help
- Renaming the plugins folder doesn't work either
- Copied wp-admin and wp-includes folder via FTP from the current 6.2 Wordpress ZIP installation. No change.
- Frontend still works.
- I see that I can access my blog via https://wordpress.com/. I can see the comments and all pages and content.
- It was possible to update all Themes from this site

Still I can open the front end. The wp-admin area is still not available.

Any idea what to do next?

EDIT:

Enabled Debug Settings

```
// Debug settings
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

No errors. Just a view warnings. And only if I disable all plugins I get a warning about a chron function missing (JetPack)